# Notification on each new entry (Insertion) in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

How can i get notification on every new insertion in sql table, i want to get the top recent entries to show in Grid View against a user, the way i was doing this is calling ajax function using JavaScript on setInterval/setTimeout, but the problem is this its hitting the database in mentioned time interval, and i just want to load the entries (call the function) only when there is new insertion in Database just to minimize the Database Hits.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you can use SignalR.

Comment: any other way, except SignalR?

Comment: from where the entries go?

Comment: Its like the Chat App, i'm storing the message (Clients) in database and while chatting i want to load(call/hit the database if there is a new message for the Client i'm chatting with), as mentioned the way i was doing is hitting the database in intervals, i want to reduce the hits, want to get a notification from which i'll decide to hit database...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using triggers and extended stored procedures that can access processes outside the SQL application. I would say though that this is not the right architecture, and extended stored procedures have additional concerns. It would be preferable to use which ever application layer is writing to the database to perform the necessary communications signalling that a new message has arrived.